# How to use PHP's 'json_decode' on the new Google Calendar v3 API results?

Tags: javascript, php, json, google-api, google-calendar-api

Here is my code:

```
$gcal_path = "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/".$gcal_url_encoded_id."/events?maxResults=".$max_Results."&orderBy=startTime&singleEvents=true&timeMax=".$time_Max."&timeMin=".$time_Min."&key=".$api_key;

$feed = json_decode(html_entity_decode(trim(file_get_contents($gcal_path))));
```

I already have everything else ready in my script, including parsing the data from the `json_decode`. The problem is that `$feed` doesn't contain any data.

However, I've tested the `$gcal_path` variable/link with a JavaScript implementation of parsing with AJAX ( e.g. `xmlhttp.open("GET","<?php echo $gcal_path ?>",true);`. and it spits out all the right JSON data.

So, why is the PHP variable empty? What am I doing wrong?

Extra info: Also, in the results I noticed this `"etag": "\"1576214503014905\""` (the number has been changed for security purposes).

How to deal with those escaped quotes, and would it inevitably effect the outcome of the `json_decode` function call, and `$feed`?

Please, help.

Comment: With java script you are making GET request, so you are able to fetch the results. But in php you are not sending HTTP request. For this change the code like below:json_decode(html_entity_decode(trim(http_get($gcal_path)))); For this you have to install PECL. check this link http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-get.php. file_get_contents is not http_request

Comment: Do you have any info on installing PECL in cPanel? Is there any other way to do this using extensions that come standard with most PHP 5.4 implementations, and hosting accounts?

Comment: So what do you get if you simply `var_dump(file_get_contents($gcal_path)`?  You might not have `fopen_wrappers` enabled on your server, in which case `file_get_contents()` cannot work with a URL.  You would need to use cURL or other HTTP library instead.  Don't worry about the quote escaping.  `json_decode()` should take of this for you be default.

Comment: in phpinfo.php `allow_url_fopen` is set to `on`.

Comment: `<?php $feed = file_get_contents($gcal_path); ?><script type="text/javascript">/* <?php echo var_dump($feed); ?>   */</script>` returns: `bool(false);`

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED!

Here's the working code:

```
$gcal_path = "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/".$gcal_url_encoded_id."/events?maxResults=".$max_Results."&orderBy=startTime&singleEvents=true&timeMax=".$time_Max."&timeMin=".$time_Min."&key=".$api_key;

// Get cURL resource.
$curl = curl_init();

// Set some options - we are passing in a user-agent too here.
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => $gcal_path,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => '{enter a user-agent string ( some can be found at: http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Chrome/) here, without the curly braces} ',
    CURLOPT_REFERER => '{enter the referrer URL, that is allowed to get the calendar JSON, here, without the curly braces}'
));
// Send the request & save response to $resp.
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
// Close request to clear up some resources.
curl_close($curl);

// Populate the '$feed' variable with decoded JSON data.
$feed = json_decode($resp);
```

Thanks @SGC for pointing me in the right direction!

You're very much appreciated!